# Android what is this View?

Tags: android, modal-dialog, android-custom-view, custom-view

I want to do something like this in my app:

[image]

I didn't found it in eclipse. What is this object called? I saw this a couple of time which makes me think this is a built-in object. If not, how can I do sg like this?
It pops up when I click on an item a list e.g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a QuickAction which is nowhere in Android API.

http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

Comment: it's probably the Quick Action Popup Dialog Bar